# Python node in SVN

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hye, i have some problem regarding about writing a node. I have a source program written in python and it seems executable in svn. I already try with eclipse with Pydev plug in but it seems not work. I dont know if my step with CMakelist.txt is wrong or Python code just cant execute with eclipse. To make it clear, i try ( http://code.google.com/p/drh-robotics-ros/source/browse/trunk/ros/playground/nodes/arduino.py?r=51 ) this project and i got this error during run my nodes.

/ros_workspace/playground/bin$ rosrun playground arduino.py
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named arduino.py below /home/farid/ros_workspace/playground
[rosrun] Found the following, but they're either not files,
[rosrun] or not executable:
[rosrun]   /home/farid/ros_workspace/playground/nodes/arduino.py

It seems not executable. Thanks for the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31232/python-node-in-svn/) by [Dejan Stankovic](https://answers.ros.org/users/2129/dejan-stankovic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-04-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The svn:executable property is automatically managed only during adds and imports, but  does not change when you use chmod on a file after that. So you need to tell svn explicitly to change the executable property of a tracked file. The command looks something like "svn propset svn:executable '*' filename"

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2012-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-04-04**:
Huh. Add that the list of things I didn't know. (And to the list of "Why use SVN anymore?")

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That means it isn't executable; you'll need to set the executable bit:

`chmod +x foo.py`

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-04-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1